# Hide/Show keyboard on a Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, onfocus, soft-keyboard, data-entry

I'm working on a project that involves the 3 platforms (IOS, Android and Windows). In the application I´m implementing a barcode scanner, that is why i want to hide the Keyboard when a Entry field is on focus. Also, the Entry includes a button that show the keyboard only in case that the user want to write by himself

I've tried to use this [package](https://github.com/masonyc/Xamarin.KeyboardHelper) but it only works for IOS/Android.
That's why I want to know how can i achieve this. It is possible to make it from a global way? or should i implement it for each platform

Comment: modify the package to support UWP and then PR your changes

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'global' that would work without someone doing the hard work of implementing that global abstraction for each platform. So basically if you don't have such a solution that works you need to implement it yourself. The package you refer to has already implementation for some platforms so you can then just implement the same abstraction for other platforms you need.